pyrcc6 not found - MacOS and Windows pyqt6
I installed PyQt6 and PyQt6-tools, but I don't get the pyrcc6 command. Everytime I get the error of pyrcc6 not found.
I tried with multiple version python from 3.8 to 3.11. I tried on both MacOS (silicon M3 Chip) and Windows, but pyrcc6 command not found.
I even tried installing with conda, but same result.

It's not supposed to be there, since it was removed starting from PyQt6.
